# java.net.UnknownHostException Can't Solve in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, webdrivermanager-java

Till Yesterday i was using Webdriver Manager it was working sucessfully. but today it is Throwing some `UnknownHostException`

My Dependinces :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is the way i used to open the browser :

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
             driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I can't find a `Perfect Solution` but am getting `some solution` which is `not clear` can you Guys help me out!

My Error :

```
[INFO] Running TestSuite
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 1.382 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] Start_Browser(Test.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 1.257 s  <<< FAILURE!
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
    at Test.LoginTest.Start_Browser(LoginTest.java:19)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
    at Test.LoginTest.Start_Browser(LoginTest.java:19)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   LoginTest.Start_Browser:19->Openbrowser.Setupbrowser:18 » WebDriverManager jav...
[INFO]
```

Comment: Let's make a try, by using : ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().version("2.41").setup(); -> Check if it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue last day. It was because there were many chrome sessions running in background.

Delete Folder and try C:\Users\yourUsername\.m2\repository\webdriver

and I restarted chrome and it worked out