# Exception caused by Internet Explorer cache not being found. java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, selenium, webdrivermanager-java

I am using [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) to handle browser drivers downloads when working with Selenium.
The drivers are being stored at default cache location. For the other browsers being used (firefox, chrome, edge) the cached drivers are detected. It appears that IE's cached driver is not detected.

```
[DEBUG] The driver version for Internet Explorer is unknown ... trying with latest
[INFO] Reading https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/ to seek IEDriverServer
[WARN] There was an error managing IEDriverServer (latest version) (java.net.UnknownHostException: selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com) ... trying again using latest driver stored in cache
[DEBUG] The driver version for Internet Explorer is unknown ... trying with latest
[INFO] Reading https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/ to seek IEDriverServer
```

When running this offline the result is an exception being thrown.

```
[ERROR] There was an error managing IEDriverServer (latest version) (java.net.UnknownHostException: selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com)
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.getDriversFromXml(WebDriverManager.java:915)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.InternetExplorerDriverManager.getDriverUrls(InternetExplorerDriverManager.java:92)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.createUrlHandler(WebDriverManager.java:797)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.download(WebDriverManager.java:649)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:567)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.fallback(WebDriverManager.java:792)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:769)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:573)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:287)
```

I have try/catch to handle this exception. Is there a fix for it?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675349/1387701

Comment: @DMart following this answer. I don't have any IE's running in the background currently and the .m2/repository directory does not contain a webdriver folder